# If vs if then statements

Tags: ruby, if-statement

What is the difference between an if and an if then statement? For example, what's the difference between:

```
if (condition)
   puts "Condition is true"
end
```

and:

```
if (condition) then
   puts "Condition is true"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write it with newlines, there is no difference. `then` keyword allows you to do this though:

```
if (condition) then puts "condition is true" end
```

which, imo, should never be used. In general, don't use `then` with `if`, the above should be written as

```
puts "condition is true" if condition
```

Comment: I personally only use `then` occasionally with a `when` in a switch statement. Usually only when I have a large number of cases with a simple expression/value, but as you stated, never with a `if`. Nor do I recall anyone else really using it that way from what I have seen.